# The selection cannot be run on any server

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I am trying to learn a bit about spring boot application. Below is the pom.xml file. The problem is that when I try to run the application on server I get the message `The selection cannot be run on server`. Not sure why this is happening.

I have checked few similar stack overflow questions listed below
["The selection cannot be run on any server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32731672/the-selection-cannot-be-run-on-any-server) and [Eclipse Maven Spring: Server Error when I try to Run As Server (Tomcat 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601193/eclipse-maven-spring-server-error-when-i-try-to-run-as-server-tomcat-7) but couldn't get a solution.

There are no errors or warnings in the problems tab of STS. Also I have configured STS to use Apache tomcat version 9.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.blog</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Please suggest what has to be done for running this application on server

Comment: Did you try running it as a `Spring Boot App / Java Application`?

Comment: Tried running it by right clicking on project, then clicked on `Run As` and then on `Spring Boot Application`. And it ran perfectly. But I require it to be hosted on a server

Comment: Please create a separate question for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are dealing with is a `Spring boot` application which has an embedded **battle tested** `Tomcat` server.

To run your application you have to run it as a `Java Application` or a `Spring Boot App`.

Check out [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) and [this](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-deploy-war-file-to-tomcat/) to find out how to deploy `Spring boot` app as a war.

Comment: this didn't gave solution but provided the direction in which I should head to. I solved it by simply adding the dependency `spring-boot-starter-web` and then when tried running again as a `spring-boot-app` the application started getting hosted on tomcat without any issues. So thanks for pointing in that direction

Answer (score 0):

Taking a real stab in the dark as I can't try the code out myself at the moment, but it could be that you just need to run the file marked with @SpringBootApplication instead of looking for running via the server option. Thats how I normally do it, but I use Intellij so maybe its slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Running the application as Java Application , Run the application as Spring Boot Application